MongoDb limit returns 100 rows even if specified more than 100
I am using mongosh and want to select all data, but it returns 100 rows even if I specify a limit more than 100. Here are the queries that I tried
db.current_documents.aggregate([{ $match: { type: "user", deleted:false } }, {$project: {name: 1, _id:0}},  {$sort: { name:1 }}, { $limit : 1000 }])

db.current_documents.find({ type: 'user', "deleted": false }, { name: 1, _id: 0 }).sort({ name: 1 }).limit(10000).toArray()

I couldn't find any other way.

Set batchSize
